# Class template argument deduction ambiguity

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Is the following code example in compliance with the C++20 standard or should it be rejected due to an ambiguous deduction?

```
template<typename...>
struct s {
    s(int) requires true {}
    s(int) {}
};
static_assert(not noexcept(s{{}})); // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/c1M397c93)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:6:28: error: ambiguous deduction for template arguments of 's'
    6 | static_assert(not noexcept(s{{}}));
      |                            ^
<source>:3:5: note: candidate function [with $0 = <>]
    3 |     s(int) requires true {}
      |     ^
<source>:4:5: note: candidate function [with $0 = <>]
    4 |     s(int) {}
      |     ^
```

---

As indicated by [CWG Issue 2628](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2628.html) that Brian Bi linked in his answer, it appears that there currently is no wording in the C++20 standard that mandates the requires-clause of a constructor to be propagated to the implictly-generated deduction guide. As a workaround, it's possible to provide a user-defined deduction guide instead:

```
template<typename...>
requires true
s(int) -> s<>;

template<typename...>
s(int) -> s<>;
```

Note that for this particular code example, the deduction guide `s(int) -> s<>;` would also work, since a user-defined deduction guide is preferred over an implicitly generated one. It seems the consideration here would be quality of error-reporting opposed to less code bloat.

Comment: I think it is a clang bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [CWG 2628](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2628.html): when the compiler forms the implicit deduction guide from the constructor `s::s(int) requires true`, that deduction guide should also have `requires true`, which makes it more constrained than the other deduction guide; but the wording currently doesn't specify that the deduction guide gets the constraint. It seems that GCC already does it, but Clang doesn't do it yet.

Comment: Regarding CWG 2628, do you happen to know why they choose for this rather convoluted example? Also, I don't see how the example provided actually causes an ambiguity, as stated by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction): *"A function template generated from a user-defined deduction guide is preferred over one implicitly generated from a constructor or constructor template."*

Comment: @303 I suspect they just chose the example where they discovered the issue, rather than the simplest possible example that illustrates the issue. I think you're right that the example is incorrect. I will let CWG know.